# How to blackbox libraries in the PhpStorm stack when using exception breakpoints

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm running some unit tests, using PHPUnit via Codeception, and when an assert fails, I'd like to focus on the line in my test class where the assertion failed.

Typically I have to copy the classname and line number from the terminal output, and use both PhpStorm's search and then "goto line" to find the place where it stopped. It's quite tiring doing this repeatedly (all day TDD).

I tried enabling "Exception Breakpoints" in PhpStorm, so the IDE stops at the line that throws the exception. This is normally fine, but in this case it's deep in the assert library. I want the IDE to automatically reverse up the stack to MY file and focus my attention there. I can do that manually in the stack frame panel, and it is at the correct line of course, but again it's repetitive and thus tiring.

I know there are blackboxing tools for Xdebug: "Skipped Paths" and "Step Filters > Skipped Paths", but these don't seem to affect the focusing of caught Exceptions.

I optimistically hoped if I blackboxed the PHPUnit library files, the exception halt-point might have to bubble upwards till it found a un-blackboxed file.

e.g.

```
Test  tests/src/Domain/TestSession/TestSessionTest.php:testStart
'2019-03-22 17:05:15' does not match expected type "object".
mylib/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/IsEqual.php:135   << It halts here
mylib/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Assert.php:2060
mylib/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Assert.php:485
mylib/tests/src/Domain/TestSession/TestSessionTest.php:93   << I want it to halt here in MY code
mylib/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php:1062
mylib/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php:913
mylib/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php:686
mylib/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php:868
mylib/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:733
mylib/vendor/codeception/phpunit-wrapper/src/Runner.php:110
mylib/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/SuiteManager.php:158
mylib/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Codecept.php:192
mylib/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Codecept.php:159
mylib/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Command/Run.php:384
mylib/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:255
mylib/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:953
mylib/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:248
mylib/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:148
mylib/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Application.php:108
mylib/vendor/codeception/codeception/codecept:43
```

I want to be shown this relevant code where the problem lies:

```
    $this->assertEquals($now, $ts->datetimeStarted);
at
mylib/tests/src/Domain/TestSession/TestSessionTest.php:93
```

Not this irrelevant code inside the assert machinery:

```
        throw new PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException(
            trim($description . "\n" . $f->getMessage()),
            $f
        );
at
mylib/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/IsEqual.php:138
```

The other oddity is, with Exception Breakpoints on, the IDE doesn't come to foreground focus like it does with normal breakpoints plus the internal focus is in the code panel, not the stack frame panel as usual. So I'm left focused at the external Terminal window (not the inbuilt IDE terminal). If it did focus the IDE window, and focused at the stack panel by default, then I could just press the down arrow three times. I could live with that level of RSI.

MacOS 10.12.6
PhpStorm 2018.3.5

Comment: Step filters are for stepping through the program, it doesn't affect breakpoints. Here's a request for the skipped paths to support exception breakpoints: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-43959

Comment: Thanks Eugene I've voted for it. If you don't do so, I will add an answer to that effect, then hopefully update it in future should it be developed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step filters are for stepping through the program, it doesn't affect breakpoints. Here's a request for the skipped paths to support exception breakpoints: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-43959

Answer (score 0):

I've found a sub-solution to one of my sub-complaints (second paragraph) which reduces the need for a full solution.

PHPStorm (2018.3) supports `file:line` format in the search box and so you don't need to use search and then go to line. This is quite a significant time saver.

So I just have to copy `TestSessionTest.php:93` from the middle of the stack trace in the terminal and double-shift, paste it into the IDE. It jumps straight to the line in the file.